# What is the best way to create .xls from datatable in asp .Net c#?

Tags: asp.net, excel, export, stimulsoft

i have a datatable and i want to export excel from that,
my datatable contains unicode characters (persian characters) and i want to convert it to .xls files correctly.
i was wonder is  it possible to do that with Stimulsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common method I use

```
       public void ExportDetails(DataTable tempDataTable, string FileName)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.IO.StringWriter objStringWriter1 = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView gridView1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter1);

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
                    Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
                    gridView1.DataSource = tempDataTable;
                    gridView1.DataBind();

                    gridView1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                    gridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;

                    gridView1.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter1);

                    gridView1.Dispose();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(objStringWriter1.ToString());

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {


                }
}
```

Comment: i have the same problem , my persian text is corrupted :(

Comment: like this : Ø¹Ø¨Ø¯ Ø§Ù„Ù‡Ø§Ø¯ÛŒ

Comment: I thing you should change encoding in your excel file

Comment: i think so , how can i do this?

Comment: Whats your current encoding

Comment: Updated anser, try now